# How to build a progressive web application using Angular Application?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I want to build a progressive web application using Angular and service workers.

I have build a prototype Angular app with Angular 6 and Angular Material. I can run it using ng serve in my local PC.

Next step, I want to run it in my Android phone as a progressive web application. But the problem is I don't know how to establish the development environment for achieve this target.

I want to know: 
1) how to run angular app at "web server for Chrome"?
2) how to test angular app at my Android phone for PWA development?

Many thanks for your answers of above questions or any relevant development samples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ng serve** doesn't support PWA (yet!).

1) Use some web server which supports HTTPS. Try below,

```
npm i http-server
http-server -o -i <IP Address> -p 8080 -S
```

2) Create self signed certificates(if you don't have a real one option) to run with HTTPS in local.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

3) In angular.json, add certificates like below to add it as part of build process.

```
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/manifest.json",
  "src/Staticfile",
  "src/key.pem",
  "src/cert.pem"
],
```